# What is dynamic DAO?

Tags: activerecord, dao

This [blog](http://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2007/01/07/activerecord-pattern-so-what/) talked about using dynamic DAO instead of activerecord. What exactly is meant by "dynamic" DAO in the context of statically typed languages? Does this apply only to statically typed languages on a VM or also to compiled languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both DAO and ActiveRecord are patterns to access data in a Database. DAO stands for "Data Acess Object". Following are the links to the relevant Wikipedia pages to read more about the individual patterns.

- ActiveRecord: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern
- DAO: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

Note that the ruby gem activerecord is an implementation of the "Active Record" patterns, which happens to have the same name as the pattern.